# MongoDB Users - Authentication Fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So Im wrecking my brain to why all my MongoDB users are getting their auth failed. Everything was working fine until I deleted a user, and since then all my users are getting denied.
Im using Altas and I have set my user as dbAdmin and given all rights, doublechecked so I didnt have a typo in the pw, that I set up the IP adress alright, made sure I copied the url right . .
Im trying to connect with a Nodejs App, this is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
// Connect to DB
const mongoURI =
    "mongodb+srv://MyUserName:<MyPassword>@cluster0.lbb8n.mongodb.net/<DbImUsing>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
// Route
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});
// Endpoint
app.post("/shortUrls", (req, res) => {});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Error message I am getting is this:

```
(node:5058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/Users/fridavbg/Desktop/MovingWorlds/urlShortv2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (/Users/fridavbg/Desktop/MovingWorlds/urlShortv2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/Users/fridavbg/Desktop/MovingWorlds/urlShortv2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5058) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Did you delete a user via the "Project Access Manager" in your Atlas control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review server log to see why authentication failed.

If you are on free or shared tier (m0/m2/m5), logs are not available and you have to guess.

Since you are using SRV URI, try explicitly specifying the auth source:

```
    "mongodb+srv://MyUserName:<MyPassword>@cluster0.lbb8n.mongodb.net/<DbImUsing>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to expand connect

```
useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
useFindAndModify: false,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
```

Also check network access in your MongoDB.
[image]

Add your current IP address.